# How to remove all click event handlers using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I'm having a problem. Basically, when a user clicks an 'Edit' link on a page, the following Jquery code runs:

```
$("#saveBtn").click(function () {
    saveQuestion(id);
});
```

By doing this, the onClick event of the save button calls the `saveQuestion()` method and passes on the ID of the question for which the 'Edit' link was clicked.

But if in the same session the user clicks edit on 2 questions, then instead of overwriting the previous `click` event handler, it instead causes 2 event handlers to run, one which might call  `saveQuestion(1)` and the other might call `saveQuestion(2)`. By doing this 1 question overwrites the other.

Is there a way to remove all previous `click` events that have been assigned to a button?

Answer (score 231, accepted):

You would use [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove an event like so:

```
$("#saveBtn").off("click");
```

but this will remove *all click events* bound to this element. If the function with SaveQuestion is the only event bound then the above will do it. If not do the following:

```
$("#saveBtn").off("click").click(function() { saveQuestion(id); });
```

Comment: Since jQuery 1.7, you should use on and off instead of bind and unbind

Comment: @LockTar can you suggest how this should be wrote instead?

Comment: @JohnMagnolia See my changes above.

Comment: .addAttr('onclick'); or .removeAttr('onclick');

Answer (score 15):

> Is there a way to remove all previous click events that have been assigned to a button?

```
$('#saveBtn').unbind('click').click(function(){saveQuestion(id)});
```

Comment: `unbind()` is deprecated as of jQuery 3.0, and use of `off()` has been encouraged since 1.7.

Answer (score 11):

```
$('#saveBtn').off('click').click(function(){saveQuestion(id)});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you used...

```
$(function(){
    function myFunc() {
        // ... do something ...
    };
    $('#saveBtn').click(myFunc);
});
```

... then it will be easier to unbind later.

Comment: How do you figure? No matter how a element's event are bound, they can always be unbound the same way... $('#saveBtn').unbind('whatever event(s)'); Now, to RE-BIND... yes, your technique may be easier in certain circumstances.

Comment: If you unbind all click events, then it's no different. But if you only wanted to unbind one specific action, I wouldn't want to rewrite that event in two places. And as you said, if I want to rebind it later, that's again easier to do, because I don't have to write the function a third time.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#saveBtn').off('click').on('click',function(){
   saveQuestion(id)
});
```

Use jquery's [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) and [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)