# Stop execution of some javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have multiple ajax requests with javascript code as response, and I need to stop execution of previos javascript code once new code was loaded, I mean to stop intervals, functions, timeouts...

**My Code :**

```
$.get("/ucmd", params, function(data) {
  var $data = document.createElement("div");
  $data.innerHTML = data;
  var em = $data.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for(var i=0;i<em.length;i++)
  {
    if(em[i].tagName === "SCRIPT")
    {
     if($("#"+em[i].id)) document.body.removeChild($("#"+em[i].id));
     var script = document.createElement("script");
     script.id = em[i].id;
     script.language="javascript";
     script.type="text/javascript";
     script.innerHTML = em[i].innerHTML;
     document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
  }
});
```

**Is it possible to make it to stop execution of previous code when new code is loaded?**

*P.S: I would like to use pure javascript code.*

**My Solution :**

```
  window.$timeout = {};
  window.$interval = {};

  window.$setTimeout = window.setTimeout;
  window.$setInterval = window.setInterval;
  window.$clearTimeout = window.clearTimeout;
  window.$clearInterval = window.clearInterval;

  window.setTimeout = function(id, code, delay) {
    if(typeof $timeout[id] !== "undefined") clearTimeout(id);
    $timeout[id] = $setTimeout(code, delay);
  }; 

  window.clearTimeout = function(id) {
    $clearInterval($timeout[id]);
    delete $timeout[id];
  };

  window.setInterval = function(id, code, delay) {
    if(typeof $interval[id] !== "undefined") clearInterval(id);
    $interval[id] = $setInterval(code, delay);
  }; 

  window.clearTimeout = function(id) {
    $clearInterval($interval[id]);
    delete $interval[id];
  };
```

Comment: "P.S: I would like to use pure javascript code."m - why? jQuery will ensure it will work cross browser... pure JS may not.

Comment: Using "pure javascript" (DOM methods) like this mixed with jQuery is the straightest path to memory leaks

Comment: @Brian if it is possible with jquery then it will be ok

Comment: @Esailija basically I use jQuery only for the requests because it ensure  cross browser compatibility, another code is pure javascript

Comment: @Esailija It was ok for me.. well let's back to the question : is it possible to stop execution of the code?

Comment: do you mean to want to stop the ajax call?

Comment: @Brian, no not the ajax call, see update on my post

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stop an existing call using `timeout()`, you can use:

```
clearTimeout(t);
```

You may be able to keep a global var to keep cou8nt of times you function is called and code the `clearTimeout()` around that...

make your calls like:

```
t = setTimeout("thing()",1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't keep track of `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` identifiers, this is simply not possible unless you refresh the whole page.

[How to stop all timeouts and intervals using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141064/how-to-stop-all-timeouts-and-intervals-using-javascript)

---

To clear all event handlers is also not trivial; you'd have to traverse the whole tree and call `.unbind()` on all of them. Perhaps you could limit the scope?

[How to remove all Click event handlers in Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825112/how-to-remove-all-click-event-handlers-in-jquery)

---

The only easy thing is making sure no functions are running, because by the time your AJAX response is being handled you're pretty sure no other code is running :)

Answer (score 1):

You can clear timeouts and intervals with these functions `clearInterval(id)` & `clearTimeout(id)` (Google them)

As of functions you can do this:

```
// Orginal function
window.myFunc = function(a,b,...){ ...your code here... }


// New function after ajax load
$.ajax({ 
    url : '/blablabla.php',
    type : 'GET',
    data : params,
    succes : function(){
        ......
        window.myFunc = function(a,b,...){ ...your NEW code here... }
    }
});
```