# How to remove a click event in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I got a button to click to show a map(slideDown). After showing, if the user click again the button, the map will hide(slideUp). I don't know how to remove the click event in the function, cause i want to detect the second click. This is my function code now:

```
function subangMap() {
    $("#mapInfo").unbind();
    $("#info").css("height", "760px");
    $("#mapInfo").text("Click here to hide map");
    $("#subangMapSlide").slideDown();


    $("mapInfo").click($("#subangMapSlide").slideUp());
}
```

This is my edit code with off(). But still not working..

```
function subangMap()
    {
    $("mapInfo").off('click');
    $("#info").css("height","760px");
    $("#mapInfo").text("Click here to hide map");
    $("#subangMapSlide").slideDown();

     $("mapInfo").click($("#subangMapSlide").slideUp());
    }
```

Comment: `unbind()` has been deprecated, you should look at `off()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825112/how-to-remove-all-click-event-handlers-in-jquery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery

Comment: @ChrisHardie `unbind()` is not deprecated but that's true, `off()` is preferred method

Comment: Ah, my bad, they're not deprecated, but they're not the preferred choice. From the jQuery site: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() and .off() methods are preferred to attach and remove event handlers on elements"

Comment: Read [jQuery bind/unbind and on/off](http://blog.mostlystatic.com/2012/07/whats-relationship-between-jquery.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

```
$("#mapInfo").click(function () {
    $("#subangMapSlide").slideToggle();
});
```