# how to make html anchor tag not click able with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html like this
(note -: I included j library on the top of page )

```
 <div class="WIWC_T1">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="call_levelofcourse();popup('popUpDiv1')">Level of Course</a>
 </div>
```

to make it not clickable i used jquery like this

```
$(".WIWC_T1 a").click(function(){
    return false ;
});
```

i tried this too

```
$(".WIWC_T1 a").off("click");
```

but onClick="call_levelofcourse();popup('popUpDiv1')" is still working on my page . what is soltuion to do it in very simple way ??

Comment: remove onClick from a

Comment: no i cant remove onclick function ...  from a tag line

Comment: This answer should help http://stackoverflow.com/a/825193/16959

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another aproach (which not uses jQuery) is to use css class:

```
.disable-anchor{
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

and then just add this class to your anchor like:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" 
   class="disable-anchor"     
   onClick="call_levelofcourse();popup('popUpDiv1')">
    Level of Course
</a>
```

P.S. [check the availability of `pointer-events`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) before using it because this is the CSS3 feature.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(".WIWC_T1 a").click(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent events, like `a` when clicking, prevent that event like this:

```
$(".WIWC_T1").on("click", function(e)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Do your code, such show a popup
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="call_levelofcourse();popup('popUpDiv1')" class="unclickable">Level of Course</a>



function call_levelofcourse(){
if(!$("a").hasClass("unclickable")){
 /* your codes here */
}
}
```

Comment: your method can work but i have more a tags with in same class and every one have different onclick function ... so i cant use your solution for every a tag

Comment: you can select anchor with $(".WIWC_T1>a") or give an exact id to the anchor. And also can try $(this) selector

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are discouraged, because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".WIWC_T1 a").on("click", function(){ 
   $(this).attr("onClick", false); 
});
```

Please remember to add Jquery prototype
Thanks Vivek

Comment: Please add  at top of your hrml page to get Jquery working<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: not working yaar  popups are still working <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="call_levelofcourse();popup('popUpDiv1')">Level of Course</a>

Comment: I tried it on Fiddle and it is working fine, Have you added jquery.js in your html page

Comment: even i can accept your method can work... but in my case    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="call_levelofcourse();popup('popUpDiv1')">Level of Course</a>    this onclick is still working your code cant prevent these fuction

Comment: OK Why cant you remove onclick event from this  anchor tag?? What is stopping you from removing it.

Comment: Please try below it will definitely work.

$(".WIWC_T1 a").on("mouseover", function(){ 
   $(this).attr("onClick", false); 
});

Comment: not that was not working i use alternate way like this       $(".WIWC_T1 a").css('pointer-events', 'none');
    $(".WIWC_T1 a").css('color', 'grey');

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".WIWC_T1 a").removeAttr('onclick');
```

Comment: i dnt want to remove them i need them  conditionally

Comment: function urFunName(){ if(urCon){ $(".WIWC_T1 a").removeAttr('onclick');}else{ $(".WIWC_T1 a").attr('onclick','call_levelofcourse();popup('popUpDiv1');');}}

Comment: You should [edit] your answer to add to the new code.