# How to Remove all the click handlers in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, click

I have d3 elements in my html page consisting of 'g' elements which contain the class bubble and their structure looks like this. When i do a click, the event registers and a click class is added. The function recordData registers the event. I need to remove all the click events on 'g' elements after one iteration so it does not register twice if any g element is repeated in another iteration. How can i remove all the event listeners on 'g' element specially the one i added in through recordData.

```html
<g id="4119-virtuality" angle="3.7699111843077517" class="bubble" transform="translate(102.63251712643411,493.138632973281)" style="pointer-events: auto; fill: black; font-weight: bold;">
  <circle r="52.21875" style="opacity:0"></circle>
  <rect rx="5" ry="5" style="fill: rgb(170, 170, 170);" x="-52.21875" y="-45" width="104.4375" height="90"></rect>
  <text text-anchor="middle" style="font-size:20" alignment-baseline="middle">
    <tspan x="0" y="0">virt</tspan>
  </text>
</g>
```

```js
function recordData(){
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName("bubble");
  for(var i = 0; i < element.length; i++){
    element[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
      var id = this.attributes.id.value;
      var index = findWithAttr(local_data, "keywordId", id);

      if(this.attributes.class.value.split(" ").indexOf("clicked") == -1)
      {
        console.log("Clicked");
        local_data[index].sub_rel = true; // Update the sub relevance to the original array
        // Store the clicked elements temporarily
        clicked_elements.push({
          id: id,
          keyword: local_data[index].keyword,
          obj_rel: local_data[index].obj_rel,
          sub_rel: local_data[index].sub_rel
        })
        var bubs = svg.selectAll(".contextbubble,.bubble");
        var b = bubs[0].filter(function(d) {return d.id === id});
        d3.select(b[0]).style("font-weight", "bold");
        d3.select(b[0]).classed("clicked", true);

      }
      else if (this.attributes.class.value.split(" ").indexOf("clicked") > -1)
      {
        console.log("Unclicked");
        local_data[index].sub_rel = false; 
        var indx = findWithAttr(clicked_elements, "id", id);
        clicked_elements.splice(indx, 1);
        var bubs = svg.selectAll(".contextbubble,.bubble");
        var b = bubs[0].filter(function(d) {return d.id === id});
        d3.select(b[0]).style("font-weight", "normal");
        d3.select(b[0]).classed("clicked", false);
      }
    }, false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove it before adding:

```
 var recordData = function() {
 var element = document.getElementsByClassName("bubble");
  for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
    element[i].removeEventListener("click", event);
    element[i].addEventListener("click", event);
  }
}

var event = function() {

  var id = this.attributes.id.value;
  var index = findWithAttr(local_data, "keywordId", id);

  if (this.attributes.class.value.split(" ").indexOf("clicked") == -1) {
    console.log("Clicked");
    local_data[index].sub_rel = true; // Update the sub relevance to the original array
    // Store the clicked elements temporarily
    clicked_elements.push({
      id: id,
      keyword: local_data[index].keyword,
      obj_rel: local_data[index].obj_rel,
      sub_rel: local_data[index].sub_rel
    })
    var bubs = svg.selectAll(".contextbubble,.bubble");
    var b = bubs[0].filter(function(d) {
      return d.id === id
    });
    d3.select(b[0]).style("font-weight", "bold");
    d3.select(b[0]).classed("clicked", true);

  } else if (this.attributes.class.value.split(" ").indexOf("clicked") > -1) {
    console.log("Unclicked");
    local_data[index].sub_rel = false;
    var indx = findWithAttr(clicked_elements, "id", id);
    clicked_elements.splice(indx, 1);


    var bubs = svg.selectAll(".contextbubble,.bubble");
    var b = bubs[0].filter(function(d) {
      return d.id === id
    });
    d3.select(b[0]).style("font-weight", "normal");
    d3.select(b[0]).classed("clicked", false);
  }


}
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DOM **`removeEventListener`** (opposite to **`addEventListener`**).

Example:

```
var element = document.getElementById("myDIV")
  , onClick = function() { /**/ };

element.addEventListener("click", onClick); // to bind handler
element.removeEventListener("click", onClick); // to unbind handler
```

Remember to save a reference to the handler function you binded with addEventListener, to remove it.

If you use **jQuery**, **Zepto.js** you can instead use `$(element).on("click", myFunction)` and `$(element).off("click", myFunction)` to unbind.

Answer (score 0):

You would use [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove an event like so:

This will remove all click events bound to this element.

```
$("#test").off("click").click(function() { //you code });
```

Look this :  [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825112/how-to-remove-all-click-event-handlers-in-jquery)